# can i avoid a parenting dependency

Tags: bones, parent

I'm wanting to know if I can avoid (i belive its called cyclic) dependency. basically, I want one bone to be a child of the other but I also want that bone to be the child of the first so they both follow each other. is there a way to do this without disabling the parenting of one of the bones? also let me know if i explained this confusingly

Edit : to be more clear, say i had 2 bones. i want bone 1 to follow bone 2 but i also want bone 2 to follow bone 1

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You described precisely your proposed solution that leads to the dependency loop you don't want, rather than tell us what you are ultimately trying to achieve so we can recommend alternatives.

Comment: You may want to see this old foot rig video or newer ones to help you talk about your goal. Because I only understand 50% of what you wrote, there is a large element of guessing. The video on foot roll .... https://youtu.be/D-rDyASHn3Q .   Of course there are many ways to get a fool roll or something similar.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos im trying to make bone A move with bone B but also make bone B move with bone A. i can provide a diagram later if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. With the amount of information you've provided, looking at the most general case, this is not possible.

Let's imagine that bone 1 follows bone 2 and bone 2 follows bone 1.  What happens when you move bone 1?  Bone 2 moves.  Now what happens to bone 1? Well, bone 2 moved, so bone 1 has to move.  Now what happens to bone 2?  Well....

The structure doesn't make sense.  It would never end.  Blender would just freeze while it got stuck in an infinite loop.

I think that typically, when people want this behavior, what they want is for the armature to adapt to whichever bone they've selected most recently-- to basically have a no-hierarchy armature, where child-of's create the hierarchy and are visually applied, deleted, and recreated in a new order every time the animator picks a new bone.  They want bone 2 to follow bone 1 only when bone 1 is selected, but bone 1 to follow bone 2 when bone 2 is selected; they want this to be updated, visually transformed, whenever they change selection.

Such a system *would* be possible to script, although it would be complicated, and it would require an extra level of user input, because sometimes, you just want to move bone 1 without moving bone 2.  In essence, the user would have to redefine the entire bone hierarchy every time they selected a new bone: which bones are moving with which, for this particular pose action?  (If they wanted to do that, they could just make a brand new rig every frame and skip the scripting.)

More, the interpolation would be terrible.  You'd keyframe at 1 and at 3 and frame 2 would be, who knows, but not something that you'd want.  Heaven forbid you think about enabling motion blur....

Because of these issues, I don't think anybody has ever written a script to do this, because it wouldn't be worth the time.  What they ended up with would be nearly unusable.

However, that doesn't mean that there aren't any techniques to help with the frustrations that cause users to wonder about this.  Sometimes, it can be by posing multiple bones simultaneously, about pivots other than individual origins.  Sometimes, it can be by creating a third control bone that has different effects on bone 1 and bone 2.  Sometimes, it might even be by using two different armatures, with different hierarchies, and animating the armature modifiers to distinguish between the two (or, better, surface deforming between two different armature deformed meshes, because the interpolation is better like that.)

However, it's hard to make recommendations about how to handle a particular frustration, without knowing exactly what that frustration is.  Solutions are specific to problems.